# Pass a query string parameter from the parent URL to a page viewer web part

Tags: query-string, page-viewer-web-part

This may be a simple question for SP2010, I am trying to get the query string from a page url and pass it to the url of a page viewer web part.

https://mysite.com/subsite/default.aspx?TeamID=X

The content in the page viewer webpart comes from a different site, but needs the TeamID.

https://othersite.com/page.htm?TeamID=X

I can set the query string manually in the page viewer url, but this is something that will be replicated many times, and I really want to find a way to set up the page viewer and not have to edit it each time I replicate the page.

Thanks in advance,